Sveltekit: error during build: "Could not detect a supported production environment.", works well in 'dev' and 'preview' mode'
I made an application with connection to MongoDB. I wanted to deploy it on Vercel. Got an error: "'MONGO_KEY' is not exported by $env/static/private, imported by src/hooks.server.js". Then I tried to build it locally and got "Could not detect a supported production environment."
package.json
{
    "name": "svelte-kit",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "eslint": "^8.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "vite": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0-next.68",
        "mongoose": "^8.4.0"
    }
}


Also I have an adapter-auto configuration:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        alias: {
            $routes: './src/routes',
            '$routes/*': './src/routes/*'
        }
    }
};

export default config;


During two month I worked at this application in order to not be able to build it. Please help.
I tried to reinstall adapter with no result.

Before this, I updated node and got an error in VS Code cannot find 'some staff' in 'directory path'. Instead of changing path variables in VS Code I copied 'some stuff' in required directory and then error desapeared. 'dev' and 'preview' work normally. Maybe this is the point?

I hardcoded key for connection to Db, then deploy successfully finished, but got 'Invalid request body' as a result...
